# Running both VMWare and VirtualBox on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vmware-player

Currently I use VMWare Player on Ubuntu 10.04 (64bit). Since I am not content with the performance of a virtual Windows XP machine, I'd like to test VirtualBox.
Is it possible to install VirtualBox on Ubuntu 10.04, when VMWare Player is already installed? I remember that the kernel was newly compiled when installing VMWare Player, and thus hesitate to install VirtualBox: the VMWare Player must stay functional.
Do you have experience with such setups? Are there some special steps to follow with such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes i've installed in my debian squeeze machine both VMWare Player and VirtualBox OSE, there is not incompatibility problem between them .

I only never run a virtual machine with VirtualBox and another with VMWare Player at the same time, for performance related issue, but yes they can be installed together in the same system and no special steps to follow.